# How to turn a list into a list of subsequent element pairs in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Is there a function in clojure which does the following:

```
(_ '(1 2 3 4 5)) => '((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5))
```

I'm pretty sure I've met something like that earlier.. can not remember what it was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with build-in [partition](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partition) function:

```
> (partition 2 1 '(1 2 3 4 5))
((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5))
```

But when people ask for "all pairs" they usially mean "all combinations". If you need all combinations - use [math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics).

Comment: correct, I formulated the title the really right. I better reformulate it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
(defn pairs [coll]
  (map list coll (next coll)))

(pairs '(1 2 3 4 5))
;;=> ((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [combinatorics](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.combinatorics) for a more general solution to all pairs (but I know this isn't what your example does).

```
Clojure=> (combinations '(a b c) 2)
((a b) (a c) (b c))
Clojure=> (combinations '(a b c d e) 3)
((a b c) (a b d) (a b e) (a c d) (a c e) (a d e) (b c d) (b c e) (b d e) (c d e))
```